# How to set TextView to other random TextView in same class?

Tags: android, text, random, textview

I would like to have a TextView in my Android App be set to another TextView in the same class randomly. I tried this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
pop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popUSA);
poprank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poprankUSA);
randomUSA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomUSA);
Random randomStat = new Random();
int random = (randomStat.nextInt(2));

if (random == 1){
randomUSA.setText(pop +"");
if (random == 2){
randomUSA.setText(poprank+"");          
}};

}
```

And it didn't work. It would show me some random text instead and wasn't changing when I reopened the app. Also, could someone tell me how to make a button that refreshes the TextView and sets it as a different random one.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

You are setting the reference ID of an object when you did this:

```
randomUSA.setText(pop +"");
```

Which is why you are getting weird texts.

Use this instead,

```
randomUSA.setText(pop.getText())
```

Second,

Random.nextInt(2) in my oppinion will never returns you 2, it only returns you 0 or 1.
If you are looking for 1 or 2 as result, use (randomStat.nextInt(2) + 1) instead.

Third,

Reference your button with an ID, and set the on click listener,

```
Button refresherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refersherButton);
refresherButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        randomUSA.setText(pop.getText());
    }
});
```

**Update with your codes:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
pop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popUSA);
poprank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poprankUSA);

// I would suggest you to pre-set something into this two textview,
// so that you can get it later.
// But of course you should set it base on your application logic, not hardcode
pop.setText("Population: 316,668,567");
poprank.setText("Population Rank: 3");

randomUSA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomUSA);
bRandomusa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRandom);
Random randomStat = new Random();

int firstRandom = randomStat.nextInt(2);
if (firstRandom == 0) {
    randomUSA.setText(pop.getText());
}else if (firstRandom == 1) {
    randomUSA.setText(poprank.getText());
}

//Use setTag here, for cleaner codes
bRandomusa.setTag(randomStat);
bRandomusa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random randomStat = (Random) v.getTag();
        int random = randomStat.nextInt(2);
        if (random == 0) {
            randomUSA.setText(pop.getText());
        }else if (random == 1) {
            randomUSA.setText(poprank.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried using .gettext instead but now nothing is showing up. Also, for the button, you said to use randomUSA.setText(pop +""); but before you said to use pop.gettext. Which one should I use.

Comment: Lets start from beginning, do you have anything inside pop and poprank textview? if .gettext shows nothing I believe there is nothing inside both textview. If there is none what are you trying to accomplish in randomUSA.setText(pop +"") referring to your codes?

Comment: Another question, when I put the if statements inside of the button's onclicklistener, it gives me an error saying that I cannot put a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method. Am I putting the if statements in the wrong place?

Comment: And in those lines I was checking to see whether the value of the random value was 1 or 2. If it was 1, it would show pop, if it was 2, it would show poprank. I then put these lines inside of the button because I thought that it would only check for the number once the button is pressed.

Comment: I believe the error happens on your random object? you can easily solve it by declaring it as `final Random randomStat = new Random()`, and for that 1 or 2 case, I'm just reminding you that `randomStat.nextInt(2)` will never returns 2.

Comment: And just a suggestion to your development flow, I would prefer that you start with setting a hardcoded text for random testing first. Use `randomUSA.setText("pop text here")` and `randomUSA.setText("poprank text here")` to make sure randomize works, and if it does, then only you continue with setting it with textview value.

Comment: This is my current code: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
pop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popUSA);  poprank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poprankUSA);
randomUSA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomUSA);
bRandomusa= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRandom);
Random randomStat = new Random();
final int random = (randomStat.nextInt(2));
bRandomusa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (random == 0){
randomUSA.setText("Population: 316,668,567");
if (random == 1){
randomUSA.setText("Population Rank: 3"); 
   }
  }}});
  
   };
}

Comment: Sorry if the formatting is weird. Now when I first launch the app, here is no randomUSA text and when I press the button, the pop text comes. When I press it again, it doesn't change. I tried multiple times and each time only the pop text comes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, thank you this worked really well. One last thing, how would I incorporate new TextViews into this?

Comment: I do not understand, can you please elaborate how you would like to add TextView? What kind of TextView and what it does?

Comment: I just wanted to add more TextViews similar to pop and poprank but with different content. Instead of the randomUSA being either of those two, I would like more TextViews to be included to be randomly chosen. I assume that I would have to increase the number from randomStat.nextInt(2) to something greater.

Comment: A `List<TextView> tvList` would help, add in all your TextViews into this tvList, and use `randomStat.nextInt(tvList.size())`, and you should know what to do next.